# Switching computers not working as expected

Tags: keyboard, multiple-monitors, mouse, macbook-pro, dell-xps

Summary: So I bought a switch [Wenter HDMI Switch 4k 60hz HDCP 2.2](https://www.amazon.es/gp/product/B08PB6ZYGQ/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o07_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) and was attempting to connect three computers on clamshell mode (two macbooks and one dell xps PC, all sharing the same monitor and if possible the magic mouse and keyboard). So in my innocence I was expecting toggling between computers smoothly and sharing the same keyboard&mouse as each computer starts using the monitor, at the very least the two macs, but in reality it's a bummer. I'm currently facing these issues

- Takes significant time to display the user lock screen (sometimes I have to press continuously any other key or even opening the case), for the macbook that is currenlty paired with the magic mouse and keyboard
- Not showing the user lock screen at all for the other macbook
- Showing the user lock screen for PC but not recognising magic mouse and keyboard

Soy my main concern is, is it possible to run thing smoothly ? should I use different approach or am I way out of line.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The slowness you describe sounds like a problem with the HDMI switch itself.  I suspect the quality of the switch to be at fault.

Comment: this appears to just be an HDMI input selector switch, not a KVM switch which lets a single keyboard/mouse to control all the computers when they are selected. standard desktop KVMs vary widely in price, and the good ones (especially for multiple monitors) can be several hundred dollars. also, computers just don't like it when their input hardware just disappears and then just reappears. they do their best to keep up, but even good solutions can be hit-and-miss. I have a very nice KVM that works 90% of the time, but ocasionally I have to unplug the source device or flip channels and back.

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys!, this is in fact a HDMI input selector switch and not a KVM. Right now I'm just using 1 monitor 1 magic mouse 1 magic keyboard with 3 computers (2 macs 1 pc). So, in order to share the monitor (first and foremost) and the mouse and keyboard (if possible), should I get a KVM switch ??

Comment: I'm not familiar with "magic mice" other than those in Cinderrella, but if that solution is working for you, you probably don't need a KVM. I do think however that your HDMI switch is likely insufficient to your needs.